# I'm not sure why this code isn't working?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, tuples

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <tuple>
void printBoard(std::vector<std::tuple<int,int>> x) {
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < x.size(); i++) {
        int trying = std::get<0>(x[i]);
        int num = std::get<1>(x[i]);
        std::cout << "Case #" << trying << ", Val = $" << num << std::endl; 
    }
}
int main()
{
    std::cout << 5 << std::endl;
}
```

I tried running this code but I am getting these errors while trying to do so:

```
DealOrNoDeal.cpp:7:34: error: no member named 'tuple' in namespace 'std'
void printBoard(std::vector<std::tuple<int,int>> x) {
                            ~~~~~^
DealOrNoDeal.cpp:7:43: error: expected '(' for function-style cast or type construction
void printBoard(std::vector<std::tuple<int,int>> x) {
                                       ~~~^
DealOrNoDeal.cpp:7:51: error: expected '>'
void printBoard(std::vector<std::tuple<int,int>> x) {
                                                  ^
DealOrNoDeal.cpp:7:28: note: to match this '<'
void printBoard(std::vector<std::tuple<int,int>> x) {
                           ^
DealOrNoDeal.cpp:7:34: error: no member named 'tuple' in namespace 'std'
void printBoard(std::vector<std::tuple<int,int>> x) {
                            ~~~~~^
DealOrNoDeal.cpp:7:43: error: expected '(' for function-style cast or type construction
void printBoard(std::vector<std::tuple<int,int>> x) {
                                       ~~~^
DealOrNoDeal.cpp:7:51: error: expected '>'
void printBoard(std::vector<std::tuple<int,int>> x) {
                                                  ^
DealOrNoDeal.cpp:7:28: note: to match this '<'
void printBoard(std::vector<std::tuple<int,int>> x) {
                           ^
DealOrNoDeal.cpp:8:34: error: use of undeclared identifier 'x'
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < x.size(); i++) {
                                 ^
DealOrNoDeal.cpp:9:34: error: use of undeclared identifier 'x'
        int trying = std::get<0>(x[i]);
                                 ^
DealOrNoDeal.cpp:10:31: error: use of undeclared identifier 'x'
        int num = std::get<1>(x[i]);
```

Which was really strange because I never had a problem with this code segment before... I am trying to build a deal or no deal game, but all it does is bringing multiple errors.  Any ideas on how I can fix this?

Comment: Are you sure you have C++11 enabled?

Comment: I know why it isn't working - it has a bug!  Seriously, try to choose more descriptive titles.

Comment: I’ll bet you could remove 95% of that code and still show the problem.

Comment: These are the errors produced when [using clang with the C++03 standard](https://godbolt.org/z/3PxhzjhqK), because C++03 does not support `std::tuple`.  When using C++11 or later, [there are no errors](https://godbolt.org/z/PrbMMcE5s).

Answer (score 3):

The errors you are getting are because you are using the wrong version of C++.

The [`std::tuple`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple) template was added in C++11.

To fix this error, I recommend changing the C++ version in your compiler's config. I use msys64 mingw64 g++ in VSC and can compile this code without errors.

How to install:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw

You can also tell clang to compile with this option: `-std=c++11`

Comment: Re: “The tuple function” — `std::tuple` is not a function. It’s a class template.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks anyways, I simply used this command instead to get my code working:

```
clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ DealOrNoDeal.cpp
```

I tried following the steps the other mentioned but couldn't do it cause microsoft windows applications cannot be opened with MacOS.

Comment: Your OS and compiler should have been part of the question.